# Pass python keywords through postman

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, postman

I am sending request  directly from my python app to an api and it works fine.

```
{
        "name": "Vs",
        "state": "inactive",
        "bu": [
            {
                "start_date": "2020-12-19 00:00:00",
                "end_date": "2020-12-20 23:59:59",
                "daily_budget": None,
                "enable_pacing": True,
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now i want to send this same json to my python from postman which i later send to api.But values like :None ,True should be double quotes when sending from postman.That is i write "None" from postman which should be recognised as None and not "None" in python.
How to do this?

Comment: `None` in Python is `null` in JS/JSON, `True` is `true`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is my answer please write it so that i can accept.